# How to check internet access (send and receive data is successful ) on Android?

Tags: android, connection, network-connection

hi i want check when a phone or tablet connected to a network (mobile or wifi).

Do this network access to the internet and send and receive data?

i use this code:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")) {
            if (ni.isConnected()) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"WIFI CONNECTED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Boolean m = isOnline();
                Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(m),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context,"WIFI NOT CONNECTED AND AVAILABLE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }


public boolean isOnline() {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {

        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);

    } catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); } 
      catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return false;
}
```

but it's always return false

(i test app in BlueStacks).

i test all codes that exist in stackoverflow

Comment: check if the try block is getting executed fully..

Comment: i check it. it not work for me

Comment: so its entering catch block..could you please tell which catch is caught? and the line in which exception occured

Comment: add a `log.e("TAG",e.printStackTrace());` to your `catch` block to show the error on the log.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try this to check if you're really connected:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                          activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

And to get the type of the connection, try this:

```
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

Check this image to see the other connection types.

[image]

Don't forget to add this line on your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

More information on [the training](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

More info on `ConnectivityManager` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).

---

**EDIT:** You could also try something like:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (info != null) {
    return info.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

---

**Second edit:** Yeah, you could also do your "ping" approach. But... I don't think it's really necessary, you could simply try the solutions above...

Comment: when I comment this lines

     // Boolean m = isOnline();
     // Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(m),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

check wifi connect worked.